# avoiding gap on the left in index when multiple entries

Tags: margins, imakeidx

When I am making an index with multiple columns and when a word is indexed a big number of times, sometimes it appears on two lines, or more, in the index. But in the lines after the first one, there is a big margin on the left, which is not beautiful and wastes some space. I would like every page number to be shown without any margin on the left after the first line.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=index1, title=XXX, columns=3, columnsep=150pt]

\begin{document}

toto\index[index1]{toto}
\clearpage
tata\index[index1]{tata}
\clearpage
toto\index[index1]{toto}
\clearpage
tata\index[index1]{tata}
\clearpage
toto\index[index1]{toto}
\clearpage
toto\index[index1]{toto}
\clearpage
tata\index[index1]{tata}
\clearpage
toto\index[index1]{toto}
\clearpage
tata\index[index1]{tata}
\clearpage
toto\index[index1]{toto}
\clearpage
tata\index[index1]{tata}
\clearpage

\printindex[index1]

\end{document}
```

And here is a picture of the margin.

[image: the margin]

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. A  patch was added  to remove the left margin.

[image: a]

This is the complete code. (Also added more content to verify the code.)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=index1, title=XXX, columns=3, columnsep=150pt]

% ********************************  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xpatch}
\tracingpatches
\xpatchcmd{\theindex}
{\let\item\@idxitem}
{\let\item\space}
{}{}
% ********************************

\begin{document}
    
    toto\index[index1]{toto}
    \clearpage
    tata\index[index1]{tata}
    \clearpage
    toto\index[index1]{toto}
    \clearpage
    tata\index[index1]{tata}
    \clearpage
    toto\index[index1]{toto}
    \clearpage
    toto\index[index1]{toto}
    \clearpage
    tata\index[index1]{tata}
    \clearpage
    toto\index[index1]{toto}
    \clearpage
    tata\index[index1]{tata}
    \clearpage
    toto\index[index1]{toto}
    \clearpage
    tata\index[index1]{tata}
    \clearpage
            
    totox\index[index1]{totox}
    \clearpage
    tatax\index[index1]{tatax}
    \clearpage
    totox\index[index1]{totox}
    \clearpage
    tatax\index[index1]{tatax}
    \clearpage
    totox\index[index1]{totox}
    \clearpage
    totox\index[index1]{totox}
    \clearpage
    tatax\index[index1]{tatax}
    \clearpage
    totox\index[index1]{totox}
    \clearpage
    tatax\index[index1]{tatax}
    \clearpage
    totox\index[index1]{totox}
    \clearpage
    tatax\index[index1]{tatax}
    \clearpage
            
    \printindex[index1]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1000 thanks, this works !